# Ошибка sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column, как исправить?

Tags: python, sqlite3, discord.py

Я пишу discord бота(discord.py) на Python, и мне нужно чтобы при включении бота создавалась и заполнялась таблица faculties в бд. Вот что я сделал:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    """Функция on_ready выполняется при запуске бота и создаёт таблицу users
    в бд, также добавляет в бд имена, id, количество xp и сервер всех
    участников, которых нет в бд.
    """
    DiscordComponents(bot)
    faculties = [
        "gryffindor",
        "slytherin",
        "hufflepuff",
        "ravenclaw"
    ]
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS faculties (
        name TEXT,
        points INT,
        server_id INT
    )""")
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for faculty in faculties:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT name FROM faculties WHERE name = {faculty}") is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO faculties VALUES ('{faculty}', 0, {guild.id})")
    connect.commit()
    print("Bot connected!")
```

Но при запуске бота я получаю такую ошибку:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\belog\hat_dispenser\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\belog\hat_dispenser\main.py", line 72, in on_ready
    if cursor.execute(f"SELECT name FROM faculties WHERE name = {faculty}") is None:
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: gryffindor
```

Comment: Попробуйте напрямую сделать запрос и посмотреть выдается ли ошибка, отправьте SELECT name FROM faculties WHERE name = 'gryffindor' и поделитесь, пожалуйста, результатами. Судя по всему из-за ошибки в синтаксисе БД пытается найти колонку вместо строки

Comment: for guild in bot.guilds:
        for faculty in faculties:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT name FROM faculties WHERE name = '{faculty}'") is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO faculties VALUES ('{faculty}', 0, {guild.id})")
    print(cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM faculties WHERE name = 'gryffindor'"))

Comment: Я поставил '' вокруг gryffindor и ошибок не возникло, когда я обращаюсь напрямую, получаю None.